# Initializing Multidimensional Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 3-multidimensional array:

```
int[][][] env;
```

which I would like to initialize with data in a text file. The data in the text file looks like this:

```
 {                                                {  { 0, 1,-1},     
                                                     { 0, 2,-1},
                                                     {-1,-1,-2},
                                                     { 0, 0, 0}   },

                                                { { 0, 0,-1},
                                                  { 0, 0,-1},
                                                  {-1,-1,-2},
                                                  { 0, 0, 0}    } 
  }
```

Actually the accolades can be removed and replaced with different characters if it is necessary. If there are any better way to format the values in the text file, then it is welcomed.

I am looking for the best way to initialize the array in the java program with the values from the text file.

Comment: Amusingly, that's nearly valid Java source code.  Maybe use Javac as your parser?  :-)

Comment: Do you have file at compile time or do you have it at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles:

```
int[][][] env =

 {                                                {  { 0, 1,-1},     
                                                     { 0, 2,-1},
                                                     {-1,-1,-2},
                                                     { 0, 0, 0}   },

                                                { { 0, 0,-1},
                                                  { 0, 0,-1},
                                                  {-1,-1,-2},
                                                  { 0, 0, 0}    } 
  }

;
```

Do you want more than this???

---

Java doesn't have `#include` if that's what you're asking. If you actually need to read the content of the file at run-time, then that's an I/O and parsing related question, not really about multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Fun!

The following Perl program transforms the data into a more digestible format, where each output line is the array indices followed by an integer value.  The program uses continued regexes (the "\G" and the "c" flag) to pick up where the last match left off.  There's a little fiddling with an array slice to handle the outer "{ ... }".

```
#!perl -w                                                                          
my $content = do {local $/=undef; <>};
my @stack = ();
my $count = 0;
while (1) {
   if ($content =~ m/\G\s*\{/cgms) {
      push @stack, $count;
      $count = 0;
   } elsif ($content =~ m/\G\s*\}\s*,?/cgms) {
      $count = pop @stack;
      $count++;
   } elsif ($content =~ m/\G\s*(-?\d+)\s*,?/cgms) {
      print "@stack[1 .. $#stack] $count $1\n";
      $count++;
   } elsif ($content =~ m/\G\s*\z/cgms) {
      last;
   } else {
      my ($err) = $content =~ m/\G\s*(.{1,20})/cgms;
      die "Syntax error: $err\n";
   }
}
```

Here's the sample output for your data set:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 2 -1
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 2
0 1 2 -1
0 2 0 -1
0 2 1 -1
0 2 2 -2
0 3 0 0
0 3 1 0
0 3 2 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 2 -1
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 2 -1
1 2 0 -1
1 2 1 -1
1 2 2 -2
1 3 0 0
1 3 1 0
1 3 2 0
```